# trigger.focus replaced by $("selector").get(0).focus() in jquery1.9?

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.9, jquery-migrate, jquery-trigger

When you .trigger("focus") in IE, jQuery won't "see" the async focus event which will occur later, so it fires one of its own to ensure that a focus event always occurs as described above. This causes two calls to the event handler. To avoid this double-call--but risk that the event handler is not called at all--use the DOM focus method directly, e.g., $("selector").get(0).focus().

This is what jquery migrate site says. Although I was not clear if every trigger.focus needs to be replaced with new implementation? IF so what would be the new code be for a simple button. trigger focus?

```
 $('#btnMove').trigger('focus');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [Order of triggered "focus" events](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#order-of-triggered-quot-focus-quot-events)

Get Native DOM Element and call focus event on it.

```
$('#btnMove').get(0).focus();
```

Or

```
$('#btnMove')[0].focus();
```

Or
Use Pure JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('btnMove').focus();
```

Comment: 'use the DOM focus method directly'.I did not get this. Does that mean selector in your answer wont be btnMove?

Comment: little more understanding on DOM element. if a btn is enclosed withing a div, is it like dom element will be div, very less knowledge here

Comment: @AdarshK no DOM element will be btn only.As you need to focus `btn` so you need `btn` only.If you want button inside div than use `$('#divID :button')[0].focus();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('#btnMove').on('focus', handler);
```

---

Also, you can read http://api.jquery.com/focus/ and a note you would find:

> Attempting to set focus to a hidden element causes an error in Internet Explorer. Take care to only use .focus() on elements that are visible. To run an element's focus event handlers without setting focus to the element, use .triggerHandler( "focus" ) instead of .focus().